# pandas - split string and take each couple

Tags: python, pandas, combinatorics, python-itertools

I have a dataframe that looks like that:

```
         IDs
  Name
  John   1,4,8
  Eric   2,9,17
  Paul   41,72,78,100
```

I need to take every combination from the `IDs` and to assign it to a new raw, so the output df should look like that:

```
        IDs
Name   
John    1,4
John    1,8
John    4,8
Eric    2,9
Eric    2,17
Eric    9,17
Paul    41,72
Paul    41,78
Paul    41,100
Paul    72,78
Paul    72,100
Paul    78,100
```

I tried several ways but none of them even start to look close to what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use `combinations` from itertools, `pd.Series`, `stack`, and `reset_index`:

```
from itertools import combinations
df.IDs.apply(lambda x:pd.Series(list(combinations(x.split(','),2))))\
      .stack()\
      .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
```

Output:

```
Name
John       (1, 4)
John       (1, 8)
John       (4, 8)
Eric       (2, 9)
Eric      (2, 17)
Eric      (9, 17)
Paul     (41, 72)
Paul     (41, 78)
Paul    (41, 100)
Paul     (72, 78)
Paul    (72, 100)
Paul    (78, 100)
dtype: object
```